# Executing python code with '-c' flag triggers bash

Tags: python, bash

I am using Python with the [command-line option `-c`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c). Printing some strings works:

```
python -c "print('foo')"
foo
```

but printing an exclamation mark triggers some bash-related error:

```
python -c "print('!')"
-bash: !': event not found
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I cannot understand why python/bash could not parse this very simple example.

Comment: With your code surrounded by double quotes `"`, it is first expanded by your shell. With single quotes `'`, the shell will take the argument as literal string: `python -c 'print("!")'` (using double quotes inside python to avoid quoting quotes)

Comment: @FlashThunder We're talking about double quotes and shell expansion, not backticks and execution.

Comment: @FlashThunder Thank you. It probably works fine for everyone.